# Custom Module with Custom Python Package - Module not found error

Tags: python, ansible

I wrote a custom python package for Ansible to handle business logic for some servers I manage. I have multiple files and they reference each other by re-importing the package.

So my package named `<MyCustomPackage>` has functions `<Function1> <Function2> <Function3>`, etc all in their own files... Some of these functions reference functions in the same package, so to do that the file has:

```
import MyCustomPackage
```

at the top. I did it this way instead of a relative import because I'm also unit testing these and mocking would not work with relative paths because of a `__init__` file in the test directory which was needed for test discovery. The only way I could mock was through importing the package itself. Seemed simple enough.

The problem is with Ansible. These packages are in `module_utils`. I import them with:

```
from ansible.module_utils.MyCustomPackage import MyCustomPackage
```

but when I use the commands I get module not found errors - and traced it back to the `import MyCustomPackage` statement in the package itself.

So - how should I be structuring my package? Should I try again with relative file imports, or have the package modify the path so it's found with the friendly name?

Any tips would be helpful! Or if someone has a module they've written with Python modules in `module_utils` and unit tests that they'd be willing to share, that'd be great also!